# process.Start causing Win32Exception on button push

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, pocketpc

I am trying to create a launcher app in `C#` for `WINDOWS POCKET PC`, the only programming language I know to make it. When I try to launch an external EXE in the same directory it throws an Win32Exception.

Here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace app
{
    public partial class SMO2010 : Form
    {
        public SMO2010()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void 2010Image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void PMLabel_ParentChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void P_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void TMLauncher_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string str = "TextMaker.exe";
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "TextMaker.exe";
            process.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

The `process.Start();` causes a Win32Exception. This is for Windows Mobile 2005.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: Here is the exception:

```
App.exe
Win32Exception

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at Launcher.Launcher_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control._InternalWnProc(WM wm, Int32 wParam, Int32 lParam)
   at Microsoft.AGL.Forms.EVL.EnterMainLoop(IntPtr hwnMain)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form fm)
   at Launcher.Program.Main()
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: Why is your constructor in uppercase? `APPLAUNCHER`?

Comment: Does that even compile?  This: `public APPLAUNCHER() { InitializeComponent(); }` isn't legal C#.  Only constructors can look like methods and not have a return type.  And, C# is case sensitive

Comment: Ok, fine, I removed the app name... now it is back

Comment: Can you try: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("cmd", $"/C start TextMaker.exe");`. Here's an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66443816/1797425) that may help you.

Comment: No, Visual Studio 2008 says it is an unrecognized character

Comment: You're going to need to be more explicit.  What does _"Ok, fine, I removed the app name... now it is back"_ mean?  What does VS 2008 say is an unrecognized character?  Do you have an error message?  I'm assuming that when you say "VS 2008", you mean the C# compiler, or, are you getting an exception at runtime.

Comment: BTW: Windows PocketPC or Windows Mobile does not have a cmd.exe !!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the exception does not say much. I assume it is simply by the application exe is not found.
As you know, Windows CE 5 based system does not know a Current Directory and the search path for executables is limitted.
Try with specifying the full path to TextMaker.exe, ie "\Programs\TextMaker\TextMaker.exe".

It is very helpful in testing such executables from cmd line. Unfortunately, Windows CE PocketPC does not have a CLI. But there is the ITS Tools which provide a prun tool which can be used on a Connected device (ActiveSync, WMDC) to issue cmds to the device. In your case I would test with 'prun "TextMaker.exe"', which will not work and then with 'prun "\Programs\TextMaker\TextMaker.exe"', which should work, as long as TextMaker.exe is PocketPC compatible.

Comment: I do that, but when I go to compile it I get a "Unrecognized escape sequence" EDIT: wrong slashes, sorry, still got the exception

Comment: Yes, as you should know, a backslash has to be used double times inside a C# (or C string). So, use
 "\\Programs\\TextMaker\\TextMaker.exe"